# populating data in two html tables using two ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i'm trying to populate two tables using two separate ajax calls. following is my code.

```
var payload = "authUserName=admin&authPassword=admin";

$.ajax({
  url: "https://appserver.dev.cloud.wso2.com/t/madusanka/webapps/projecttracker-default-SNAPSHOT/services/projecttracker/userservice/user/1/projects",
  type: "POST",
  async: false,
  dataType: "json",
  data: payload,
  complete: function(data) {
    alert("complete " + JSON.stringify(data));

//            for(var i = 1; i<= data.projects.project.length; i++){
//                  var tableRow = "<tr><td>" + data.projects.project[i].projectName + "</td><td>" + data.projects.project[i].startDate + "</td><td>" + data.projects.project[i].endDate + "</td><td>" + data.projects.project[i].statusId + "</td><td>" + "delete"  + "</td></tr>";
//                  $("#projectListTable tbody:last").append(tableRow);
//         }

  }
}).then(function(data) {

    alert("started");

    var payload2 = "authUserName=admin&authPassword=admin";

    $.ajax({
      url: "https://appserver.dev.cloud.wso2.com/t/madusanka/webapps/projecttracker-default-SNAPSHOT/services/projecttracker/userservice/user/1/projects",
      type: "POST",
      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      data: payload2
    }).then(function(data) {
        alert("ended");
        for(var i = 1; i<= data.projects.project.length; i++){
          var tableRow = "<tr><td>" + data.projects.project[i].projectName + "</td><td>" + data.projects.project[i].startDate + "</td><td>" + data.projects.project[i].endDate + "</td><td>" + data.projects.project[i].statusId + "</td><td>" + "delete"  + "</td></tr>";
          $("#userTable tbody:last").append(tableRow);
        }
     });                        
 });
```

If i run above code as it is it will execute well and execute whatever functions in "then".

When i uncomment the commented for loop, it won't execute beyond that for loop. after populating project list table it simply stop executing. therefore "then" functions won't get executed. it seems only one table data population loop can be there.

I want both tables to be populated one after other using ajax. I'm really confused about this. Can someone point me in correct direction?

Comment: Have you tried looking in the console for any errors? Hit F12 to open the console (on IE and Chrome, at least) and see if you get an error when the for-loop runs.

Comment: thanks for the response. i got it fixed. i have done a silly mistake by starting for loop with 1. it should be starting with 0 actually.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to have both `complete` and `then` callback functions? Looking at your codes, they don't seem to do anything different. You might as well just merge them like this:

```
var payload = "authUserName=admin&authPassword=admin";
$.ajax({
  url: "https://appserver.dev.cloud.wso2.com/t/madusanka/webapps/projecttracker-default-SNAPSHOT/services/projecttracker/userservice/user/1/projects",
  type: "POST",      
  dataType: "json",
  data: payload,
  complete: function(data) {
    alert("complete " + JSON.stringify(data));

    for(var i = 1; i<= data.projects.project.length; i++){
      var tableRow = "<tr><td>" + data.projects.project[i].projectName + "</td><td>" + data.projects.project[i].startDate + "</td><td>" + data.projects.project[i].endDate + "</td><td>" + data.projects.project[i].statusId + "</td><td>" + "delete"  + "</td></tr>";
      $("#projectListTable tbody:last").append(tableRow);
      $("#userTable tbody:last").append(tableRow);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Actually i wanted two ajax calls with two different urls,but i was testing with same url. 
yes,i can put everything in complete but result was same.
btw, I got it fixed. it was a silly mistake where i started with 1 in for loop but array was actually starting with 0.